# Java compositions accessing errors

Tags: java, class

I have this class whose main purpose is composition.
These lines are in the main class:

```
Game myGame = new Game(getRandomPositions(), player);

System.out.println("Current Play No: " + (myGame.getPlayCount()+1) + "\n");
myGame.getBoard().displayBoard();
```

I get an error in this line:

```
myGame.getBoard().displayBoard();
```

This is part of the game class:

```
public class Game {
    private Player player;
    private Board board;
    private static final int MAX_RABBITS = 3;
    public Game(int[] rabbitPositions, Player player)
    {
        this.player=player;
    }

    public Board getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
}
```

This are some parts of the Board class:

```
 public class Board {
    public static final int NUM_SPACES = 16;

    public Board(int rabbitPositions[])
    {
        //FIXME
    }
    public void displayBoard()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

I'm wondering what I'm missing? Is the getter for the board correct?
The `displayBoard` works fine when I directly access it.
I want to know how to initialize the board constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the object `board` in your contructor:

```
public Game(int[] rabbitPositions, Player player){
    this.player=player;
    this.board= new Board(rabbitPositions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the Board class in Game constructor as it have the same data type rabbitPositions that required for initialling the Board class

```
public class Game {
        private Player player;
        private Board board;
        private static final int MAX_RABBITS = 3;
        public Game(int[] rabbitPositions, Player player)
        {
            this.player=player;
            //initialising the board class
            this.board= new Board(rabbitPositions);
        }

        public Board getBoard() {
           //now it will not none
            return board;
        }

        public Player getPlayer() {
            return player;
        }
    }

public class Board {
    public static final int NUM_SPACES = 16;

    public Board(int rabbitPositions[])
    {
        //do stuff with rabbitPositions
    }
    public void displayBoard()
    {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```